# How can't Type Array object list in TypeScript Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

option.ts

```
export class Option {
  id_cat: number;
  name_cat: string;
  image_cat: string;
  option_sub : {
    id_sub:  number;
    name_sub: string;
    icon_sub: string;
    ref_id_cat: number;
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xyaZ.png)

in Json

```
{"id_cat":4,
"name_cat":"Food",
"image_cat":"","option_sub":[{"id_sub":6,"name_sub":"American Food","icon_sub":"icon ion-pizza","ref_id_cat":4}]}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a5Xo.png)

I Want to Create MegaMenu

What type option_sub T_T in Angular2

```
  option_sub :Array<{
    id_sub:  number;
    name_sub: string;
    icon_sub: string;
    ref_id_cat: number;
  }>;
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is or what the actual and expected behavior is.

Comment: Try explaining your problem a little bit.

Comment: Sorry, I set name wrong in template Not Error in TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another Typescript class:

```
export class Option {
  id_cat: number;
  name_cat: string;
  image_cat: string;
  option_sub : OptionSub[];
}

export class OptionSub {
    id_sub:  number;
    name_sub: string;
    icon_sub: string;
    ref_id_cat: number;
}
```